# What is the event that will fire after cancelling the order in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, event-observer, magento-2.1

I am trying to do something customization from my custom module after an order has been cancelled (**Frontend** as well **Backend**). For this I have gone through **cancelled** `Observer` on the `sales/etc/events.xml` and `sales/etc/adminhtml/events.xml`, But I can't find where it is.

Could you please help me where it is(Observer)? to do something after cancelled the order **Frontend**(`Customer`) and **Backend**(`Vendor/Seller`).

Which observer will use from frontend and backend?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The event you're looking for is `order_cancel_after` and it's dispatched in the `cancel` method of `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order` :

```
public function cancel()
{
    if ($this->canCancel()) {
        $this->getPayment()->cancel();
        $this->registerCancellation();

        $this->_eventManager->dispatch('order_cancel_after', ['order' => $this]);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: How to send mail using above event? Its default not sending mail for order cancel

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya; were you able to send Order Cancel email using the event `order_cancel_after`?

Comment: I am unable to call the event `order_cancel_after` when a customer or an admin cancels an order? It seems this event is not being called when order is cancelled either from store front or admin

Answer (score 2):

six types of Cancel events for Orders in Magento 2

```
1. order_cancel_after
```

This event is used after order canceled. If you want to do something after an order is canceled you can use this event.
Check file, `vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order.php at cancel()` function.

```
2. sales_order_invoice_cancel
```

Allows you to cancel the order invoice when you canceled the order.
Check event called at, file, vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php at cancel() function.

```
3. sales_order_payment_cancel_invoice
```

Allows you to cancel the order invoice when you canceled the order.
Check event called at, file, `vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php at cancel()` function.

```
4. sales_order_payment_cancel_creditmemo
```

Event defined under `vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment.php using cancelCreditmemo()` function but this function is not called at any file. Might be used in future developments. This event contains payment and specified creditmemo object.

```
5. sales_order_payment_cancel_invoice
```

Cancel specified invoice from order and update self-total from order invoice.
Event defined under `vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment.php`

```
6. sales_order_creditmemo_cancel
```

When you want to refund from a specific order or specific item from order,
Your best suitable event is, sales_order_creditmemo_cancel

More detail you can review rakesh sir blog https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/different-types-of-cancel-events-for-orders-in-magento-2/