# Magento 2 Send email after order is canceled

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I searched the internet and founded nothing.

I need to send an email to customer when the order is canceled. I've founded the trigger `order_cancel_after` when the order is canceled, but that' all i founded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the event will fire after cancelled the order in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150504/what-is-the-event-will-fire-after-cancelled-the-order-in-magento-2)

Comment: But there is no solutions

Comment: I updated the comment in chat please check it

Comment: Please let me know you are checked?

Answer (score 3):

`order_cancel_after` -> it's dispatched in the cancel method of `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order` :

```
public function cancel()
{
    if ($this->canCancel()) {
        $this->getPayment()->cancel();
        $this->registerCancellation();

        $this->_eventManager->dispatch('order_cancel_after', ['order' => $this]);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

**Source :** [What is the event will fire after cancelled the order in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150504/what-is-the-event-will-fire-after-cancelled-the-order-in-magento-2)

---

Magento does send a number of transnational emails, including cancellation. (e.g. order status change); the only issue with a cancellation email, requires the customer service agent cancelling to click `Notify Customer`. You can edit this to be the default.

To enable emails on order comments, go to `Store > Configuration > Sales > Sales Emails` and make sure order comment is enable. It take from your E-mail template

---

**FYI :** This `class Magento\Sales\Helper\Data` send all email for order transaction.

Comment: yeah, i said i know the method to cancel order. But how to send email when this method is called?

Comment: okey i will provide

Comment: I provide the comments :)

Comment: hmm, but methods in Magento\Sales\Helper\Data should be called somewhere.

Comment: check Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\History

Comment: it didn't helped :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61686/discussion-between-faik371-and-rama-chandran).