# cancel an order customer did not receive an email

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-email

I like to send an email to customer if admin cancel an order.

[image]

Please help to solve the solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Trigger and email after 'order_cancel_after' event @mohana

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran tell you the right event observer for more detail please check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150504/what-is-the-event-that-will-fire-after-cancelling-the-order-in-magento-2

Comment: Hi, i'm new to this one, please let me know how to "Trigger and email after 'order_cancel_after' event ". it's in "\Magento\Sales\Model\Order" file

Comment: No ....@prathap